# collecting numbers and printing them

Tags: c, random, string-concatenation

What I'm trying to accomplish is generating 100 random 0's and 1's add them all into one variable and then print it. What I have right now I don't know how to make work. If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

```
randstring (void){
    int i;
    int num;
    char buffer[101];
    i=100;
    while(i>0, i--){
        num = rand()%2;
        strcpy(buffer, num);
    }
    return(buffer);
}
```

What i have now is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main (void){
    printf("%f", randstring());
}
randstring (void){
    int num;
    char buffer[101];
    int i = 100;
    while(i-- >= 0) buffer[i] = rand() % 2;
    return(buffer);
}
```

Comment: as @alamar pointed out, you want characters '0'(=48) and '1'(=49) not 0 and 1

Comment: And I'd recommend also:
Adding {} to while because it would be clearer
Dropping () from return, it's not a function.

And! You can't return buffer! You need either to allocate it in main statically and pass, or allocate it in randstring dynamically (using malloc)

Comment: chnage buffer[i] = rand() % 2;  to buffer[i] = (rand() % 2) ? '1' : '0';

Comment: I've updated my answer below to use a dynamic length. Haven't compiled as I don't have a C compiler handy!

Comment: That's why programming on windows considered harmful. You don't have anything handy, unless you installed a 500M IDE.

His other problems are that he didn't forward-declare randstring(), and that he uses prinf("%f") for printing string.

Comment: eh? im doing this in linux...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `buffer[i] = (rand() % 2) ? '1' : '0';`  in the loop body?

And I'd do buffer[100] = 0;

But the worse problem is that you can't return buffer, because as soon your function exits, it would be overwritten. It is allocated on the stack, and the stack gets reused when function exits. You need to either do malloc and free, or pass buffer and its length to this function.

Which gives us:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RAND_LENGTH 100

char *randstring (char *buffer, int length);

int main (int a, char **b){
    char buffer[RAND_LENGTH + 1];
    printf("%s", randstring(buffer, RAND_LENGTH));
}

char *randstring (char *buffer, int length){
    int i = length;
    while(--i >= 0) {
        buffer[i] = (rand() % 2) ? '1' : '0';
    }
    buffer[length] = 0;
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks. as you can tell im just learning here so thanks for explaining it a bit, now to decode what you did and learn :).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int i = 100;

while(i-- >= 0) buffer[i] = rand() % 2;
```

Comment: This is not good: you fill character buffer with 0 and 1. It will be not printable. What he probably wanted is '0' and '1'.

Comment: this is working well but the return gives me the error of
main.c:35: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
main.c:35: warning: function returns address of local variable
all done